# JOLT transformation moves fields into each element of arrays

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I want to move the "id" field to each of elements in "user_roles" field of the document below.
I used the spec below but it didn't work as I expected, I'm not sure where I may have made an error in the JOLT specification.

**Input**:

```
{
      "id": "657a9dc588b19",
      "user_roles": [
        {
          "role": 2,
          "status": 1,
          "is_owner": true
        },
        {
          "role": 5,
          "status": 1,
          "is_owner": true
        },
        {
          "role": 3,
          "status": 1,
          "is_owner": true
        }
      ]
    }
```

**Spec**:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "user_roles": {
        "*": {
          "_id": "user_roles[&0]._id",
          "*": "user_roles[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Expected result**:

```
{
  "user_roles": [
    {
      "id": "657a9dc588b19",
      "role": 2,
      "status": 1,
      "is_owner": true
    },
    {
      "id": "657a9dc588b19",
      "role": 5,
      "status": 1,
      "is_owner": true
    },
    {
      "id": "657a9dc588b19",
      "role": 3,
      "status": 1,
      "is_owner": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the spec below with just a minor change in your spec.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "user_roles": {
        "*": {
          "@2,id": "user_roles[&1].id",//go one level up and get the id value
          "*": "user_roles[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Nice to help you @hoa.le

Answer (score 1):

There is one more way to achieve the expected output.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "user_roles": {
        "*": {
          "@2,id": "&2[&1].id",
          "*": "&2[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: That's your preference I respect Bhavna, but I think combining both answers within a single one would seem to be nicer ...

Comment: Yes @BarbarosÖzhan we can do that, thanks for you suggestion!